# Designing a Mechanism to Improve the Efficiency of Applications Deployed on Parachains?

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, parachain, relay-chain

As I was going through the mechanism of working of `parachains` , I came across a scenario that currently the time taken from collator producing a block on a parachain, to that block becoming finalised, is prohibitive to some `applications` deployed on the parachain, so there is a need to develop a `module` so that users can see `quasi-finalized blocks` on parachains without affecting the actual working of relay chain and parachains.It would be great if someone would share ideas related to the same.

Comment: It seems like you're asking to read events/storage from non-finalized blocks which is already possible with `polkadot-js` RPC subscriptions `subscribeNewHeads`.

Comment: I aim to formulate a sub consensus mechanism where collators within a parachain are required to reach an agreement regarding the finalization of blocks, without actually finalizing a block.

Comment: Ah I see. So you're aiming to rely on collator based finalization (just for consumption on UI), rather than wait 12 seconds for the relay chain mechanism? Strictly speaking it does undermine the consensus guarantees provided by the relay chain and it does look like the dApp's source of truth would be the collator blocks and not the relay-chain finalized block in which case, you must have a conflict resolution mechanism. Why then is there a need for the parachain? It seems what you're describing is a traditional blockchain network where the network's validators are the source of truth.

Comment: Actually I am working on creating a mechanism that allows decentralized applications (dApps) deployed on parachains to access quasi-finalized blocks that have been validated by collators but have not yet been fully finalized. This way, dApps won't need to wait for extended periods and can access these quasi-finalized blocks. This approach differs from the traditional blockchain setup where blocks are only considered finalized once they are confirmed by the relay chain. We are adding an additional mechanism to enable dApps to view and use quasi-finalized blocks before they are fully finalized.

Comment: Sorry but that's not too different from what I wrote. Also a parachain is not considered a traditional blockchain, that place is reserved for nodes acting as executors plus validators. I am still failing to grasp what is the real question you're asking here.